# Mysql triple equal problem for number data type

Tags: xampp, mariadb, mysql-error-1064

I have a student_details table. Where Roll is the primary key and a total of 8 student lists are present (101 to 108). Now I am going to test the following SQL command

```
    SELECT * FROM student_details
    WHERE Roll === 105 AND Roll === 107;
```

but I face this error

> *#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
> near '== 105 AND Roll === 107 LIMIT 0, 25' at line 2*

here Roll no 105 and 107 both are Number datatype. Why do I face this error?

Comment: By reading the MariaDB error and checking the [manual on operators](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/operators/) you will see there is no triple equals, double equals or even quad equals. One is sufficient. `Roll`  cannot be both 105 `AND` 107 at the same time. Do you mean `OR`?

Answer (score 1):

MySQL does not have a `===` operator. It doesn't have a `==` operator either.

SQL is not Javascript or PHP. It has different syntax.

SQL only has a single-equal sign (`=`) as an equality comparison operator.

Read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html for details.

The matching documentation page for MariaDB is https://mariadb.com/kb/en/comparison-operators/.